# Cannot Move Events Between Calendars (Google Calendar API)

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using the [Google Python](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/calendar_v3.events.html#move) module and trying to move an event from one user's calendar to another.

I have a service account set up and am using domain-wide delegation and I've confirmed that the service account has the necessary `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` scope, and even added on the redundant `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events` scope.

When I instantiate the Calendar object as user A or user B, I can read, create, delete, modify events to my heart's content on either calendar. But I cannot move an event from one calendar to the other.

I should also note that, in our org, all users have "read" access to everyone else's calendars, with a few exceptions that aren't relevant for this example.

How do I accomplish this with domain-wide delegation?

Example: User A has event '123456' that I wish to move to User B's calendar. A GoogleCalendar instance has been instantiated as `user_a` and `user_b`, respectively.

```
# Pushing
user_a.events().move(calendarId='user_a@domain.com', eventId='123456', destination='user_b@domain.com').execute()
user_a.events().move(calendarId='primary', eventId='123456', destination='user_b@domain.com').execute()
# Pulling
user_b.events().move(calendarId='user_a@domain.com', eventId='123456', destination='user_b@domain.com').execute()
user_b.events().move(calendarId='user_a@domain.com', eventId='123456', destination='primary').execute()
```

I've even tried using an unrelated Google Admin account and each time, I get this error:

```
"You need to have reader access to this calendar.". Details: "[{'domain': 'calendar', 'reason': 'requiredAccessLevel', 'message': 'You need to have reader access to this calendar.'}]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests, and the only way I got this error message:

```
"You need to have reader access to this calendar.". Details: "[{'domain': 'calendar', 'reason': 'requiredAccessLevel', 'message': 'You need to have reader access to this calendar.'}]"
```

Was when the user that is currently running the code or (being impersonated) in case of a services account, is no doesn't have `Super Admin` role or if the user is not `Super Admin` it should have [permissions](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en#:%7E:text=Share%20a%20calendar%20with%20specific%20people) to `Make changes to the events` in the destination account.

[image: permissions]

I made the following 2 tests, and both of them work for me using impersonation:

1. Impersonate a `Super Admin`, and move the event between 2 `non-Super Admin` accounts.

```
def move_event():

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'serviceaccount.json'

    user_1 = 'non-super-Admin-1@domain.com'
    user = 'super-Admin-@domain.com'
    user_2 = 'non-super-Admin-2@domain.com'

    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
        scopes=SCOPES,
        subject=user)

    
    event_ID = '123456'

    try:
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        updated_event = service.events().move(
            calendarId=user_1, eventId=event_ID,
            destination=user_2).execute()

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        event = None
    return event


if __name__ == '__main__':
    move_event()
```

2. Moving an event from a `Super Admin` account to a `non-Super Admin` account.

   *Note: It also works to move the event between 2 non-Super Admin accounts with the permission to make changes to the event.*

```
def move_event():

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'serviceaccount.json'

    user_1 = 'non-super-Admin-1@domain.com'
    user = 'super-Admin-@domain.com'

    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
        scopes=SCOPES,
        subject=user)

    
    event_ID = '123456'

    try:
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        updated_event = service.events().move(
            calendarId='primary', eventId=event_ID,
            destination=user_1).execute()

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        event = None
    return event


if __name__ == '__main__':
    move_event()
```

Lastly, creating the token as a `Super Admin` and moving the event between 2 `non-Super Admin` accounts.

```
def move_event():

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

    user_1 = 'non-super-Admin-1@domain.com'
    user_2 = 'non-super-Admin-2@domain.com'


    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    
    event_ID = '12345'

    try:
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        updated_event = service.events().move(
            calendarId=user_1, eventId=event_ID,
            destination=user_2).execute()

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        updated_event = None
    return updated_event


if __name__ == '__main__':
    move_event()
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I wish the documentation indicated that full super_admin was required to move between calendars. That seems a bit extreme.

Do you know if there's an admin role/permission/delegation that can be layered on to allow that without the full god-level super-admin role?

Comment: I think it is because the `Super Admin` role can view all the calendars of the domain, as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1084780). I think they added a new custom role for calendar, you can see the information [here](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/02/new-calendar-admin-privilege-hierarchy.html).